# Quicktime 7 API for Windows - couldNotResolveDataRef

Tags: c++, windows, quicktime

I'm trying to use the Quicktime 7 API for Windows (I know) because eventually I'm going to try to change the audio channel layout flags in Quicktime files, but right now I'm simply trying to create a "Movie" object.

I'm very familiar with languages like Python and JavaScript, but very new to C++. Despite that, I'm able to get the following code to all link up and compile nicely:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Movies.h>
#include <QTML.h>


int main()
{
    std::string mystring = "D:/CodingProjects/testfiles/mytestfile.mov";
    OSErr initerr = InitializeQTML(0L);
    OSErr entererr = EnterMovies();

    Movie myMovie;
    short myResID;
    Size mySize = (Size)strlen(mystring.c_str()) + 1;
    Handle myHandle = NewHandleClear(mySize);

    BlockMove(mystring.c_str(), *myHandle, mySize);

    OSErr newmovieerr = NewMovieFromDataRef(&myMovie, 0, &myResID, myHandle, URLDataHandlerSubType);
}
```

It all seems to run well, with `initerr` and `entererr` returning 0, and the entire program also exiting with 0. The problem is in the `NewMovieFromDataRef` function. `newmovieerr` seems to be returning code -2000 and not assigning anything (`0x00000000`) to `myMovie`. After looking this up, it turns out that this error code is a Quicktime error that means "couldNotResolveDataRef".

I've also tried creating a `Movie` using the function `NewMovieFromHandle` and got the same error code.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested. I finally got it to work with this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Movies.h>
#include <QTML.h>


int main()
{
    std::string mystring = "D:\\CodingProjects\\_ffmpeg\\test.mov";
    OSErr initerr = InitializeQTML(0L);
    OSErr entererr = EnterMovies();

    CFStringRef inPath = CFStringCreateWithCString(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), mystring.c_str(), CFStringGetSystemEncoding());    

    Movie myMovie;
    short myResID;
    Size mySize = (Size)strlen(mystring.c_str()) + 1;
    Handle myHandle = NewHandle(mySize);
    OSType myDataRefType = NULL;

    OSErr datareferr = QTNewDataReferenceFromFullPathCFString(inPath, kQTWindowsPathStyle, 0, &myHandle, &myDataRefType);
    OSErr newmovieerr = NewMovieFromDataRef(&myMovie, 0, &myResID, myHandle, myDataRefType);

}
```

A big part of it was using `\\` in the path instead of `/`, and also using `CFStringCreateWithCString` to get a `CFStringRef` to pass into `QTNewDataReferenceFromFullPathCFString` to get the proper `Handle` and `OSType` to then pass into `NewMovieFromDataRef`.